# Ligand Field Theory with non-identical ligands?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Lots of undergraduate inorganic textbooks deal with complexes with $O_h$ or $T_d$ symmetry. So, if ligands are not same(like $\ce{[Ni(NH_3)_4(H_2O)_2]^{2+}}$), what methods are used to interpret their properties like electronic spectra?

Comment: What do you mean by methods to interpret? Do you mean predicting their electronic spectra just by looking at their configuration or do you mean experimental methods?

Comment: Something like molecular orbital diagram or Tanabe-Sugano diagram... Is there any way to explain like 'transition from A state to B state corresponds to this peak in electronic spectra'?

Comment: Just use the lower symmetry of $D_\mathrm{4h}$?